# How to find Dataframe columns are one to one or one to many mapping in pyspark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have A Data frame like below:

```
df0 = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (1, 2)
   ]).toDF(["id",'t'])
```

when i am executing show:

```
df0.show()
+---+---+
| id|  t|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

i want to identify relationship  between  columns id, t.
in give `df0` relation between `id` column and `t` is one to many, because id column 1 and t column 3 i.e(1,3) and  next (1,2). so one to many

my expected output will be like below:

```
+---+---+---+
|idt| id|  t|
+---+---+---+
| id| OO| OM|
|  t| OM| OO|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Have you tried using `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by grouping and counting.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def relation_type(df, fromCol, toCol):
    df2 = df.groupBy(fromCol)\
    .agg(F.countDistinct(toCol).alias('val_count'))\
    .agg(F.max('val_count').alias('max_rel_count'))

    return df2.withColumn('mapping', when(df2['max_rel_count'] > 1, 'OM')\
                   .otherwise('OO'))\
                    .drop('max_rel_count')

def relation_types(df, cols):
    schemaArr = [StructField('ColName', StringType(), True)]
    for i in cols:
        schemaArr.append(StructField(i, StringType(), True))
    schema = StructType(schemaArr)
    result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
    for i in cols:
        rowDict = []
        rowDict.append(i)
        for j in cols:
            val = relation_type(df, i, j).collect()[0]
            rowDict.append(val['mapping'])
        row = sqlContext.createDataFrame([rowDict])
        result = result.union(row)
    return result
```

then call it with the columns you want

```
relation_types(df, ['id', 't']).show()
```

the result

```
+-------+---+---+
|ColName| id|  t|
+-------+---+---+
|     id| OO| OM|
|      t| OM| OO|
+-------+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi Lev Denisov, many thanks for your help, it working as expected, but we are returning getting different data frames. but I want one dataframe  with  all result can please help me on this.

Comment: Why do you want it? What is the problem tou are trying to solve? I cannot imagine why you would need the output that you want. Tell me more about the case, maybe it has an easier solution.

Comment: @RkC I updated the code so now the output is in the format you wanted